# Is the word "did" a verb or a helping verb in "I did the best I could."?

Tags: grammar, verbs, american-english

I think "did" work as a normal verb in this situation, but I'm not sure about it. I would like to have your opinion. Thank you!

Comment: ***Did*** would be a "helping verb" in, say, [I did **do** the best I could](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+did+do+the+best+I+could%22), where it implies emphasis / refutation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To do one's best* is an idiom which means *to do something as well as one can*, so the sentence may also read:

> I did everything I could.

or

> I did my best.

In both examples the verb *to do* has its literal meaning of *to carry out an action/actions*, so *did*, in the examples, is just the past form of the verb.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "I did the best I could" - there's no need to change it. "I did my best" doesn't mean quite the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Helping verbs are verbs that help the main verb in a sentence by extending their meaning. There are two types of verbs that can be used as helping verbs.

- Auxiliary Verbs
- Modal Verbs

**Auxiliary Verbs**

These verbs mainly used to express tense or add emphasis.

- I *am* having a cup of tea.
- She *is* writing a letter.
- You *did* not do the best you could!

Here as you can see *am*, *is* & *did* are helping verbs to help the main verb to represent the tense of the sentence.

**Modal Verbs**

Modal verbs further modify the action or meaning of the main verb.

- She *can* sing that song.
- You *should* learn English.

Here *can* and *should* are modal verbs.

So in your question, as you can see *did* does not help any verb to express the tense in that sentence. *did* is the only verb in your sentence. So, it is indeed the main verb, not a helping verb.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: You misspelled *modal*.

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra Thank you. I have corrected it.